# Hyperlink among local file doesn't work in NodeJS express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I made a simple express js :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var port = process.env.PORT || 1212
app.set('port', port)

app.listen(port, () => {
    const now = new Date()
    console.log(`${now} : 1212 Listening`)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
```

And I made a simple index.html :

```
<a href="index2.html"> Move to index2.html </a>
```

When I connect http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1212, index.html is displayed properly.

Obviously, index.html and index2.html are located same directory, but that link(to index2.html) doens't work.
Webpage appears cannot GET /index2.html and console log shows 404 Not found error.
How can I fix it so that link to index2.html works?

I located html files same directory, but link doens't work. Let me know how to fix it

Comment: If you want to serve local files, there is easy middleware included in express: `express.static` (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Otherwise, what happens make a lot of sense in your current code: when anybody goes to `/` on your site, the handler will send back `index.html`, as thats the file you are reading and who's data you are returning. It will _never_ return anything else, as you hardwired index.html in it. You could try to map the request to a local file yourself, but at that point you are much better off using `static`, as a lot of issues have already been solved.